# No such module error when trying to create framework with ARCore as dependency

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, arcore, xcframework

I'm looking to create a framework A which has ARCore from Google as a dependency, and distribute it ideally as an independant XCFramework, but right now, any way I can distribute it is good enough (for exemple via Cocoapods).
I only use the GeoSpatial module of ARCore it this developement.

When I work on the framework on its own, I have no issues adding ARCore in its podfile, adding "import ARCore" and making all of its feature work as expected.

But when I go and try to integrate my framework to an app, I get the same error over and over "No such module: ARCore".
ARCore is recognized in the sample app though, but not in my framework anymore.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mZZbs.png)

The podspec in my framework is

[Framework podspec](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cyauI.png)

The podfile in my sample app is

[Sample App podfile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bJOv7.png)

What I tried to do to fix it :

- Adding import ARCore in the sample app
- Adding/Removing the spec.static_framework = true in my podspec. (I believe keeping it is the right move)
- I used use_modular_headers! in my podfile instead of use_frameworks !, (and also tried to remove it but I believe keeping it is the right way)
- I also tried to archive and build my framework as an XCFramework, and use vendored_frameworks in my podspec, but not only did I see the same "no such module" error but I could see that my archive did not embed the ARCore frameworks. I know nested xcframeworks are not recommanded but it feels like this is linked to the problem.

The only way I can make the sample app compile is to import ARCore as modules, like below.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O5wVw.png)

But then the framework on its own does not compile anymore with error "could not build objective-c module arcorebase" and "inferred submodule require a module with an umbrella" in my modulemap.

The fact that ARCore presents itself as xcfameworks with submodule seems to be the reason it does not work as expected but I can't seem to figure out why.

Any help would be much appreciated!